# Correlation between timestamps

Tags: python, statistics, timestamp, correlation

I hope this isn’t off topic, I am not really sure which forum to use for a question like this:

I have a series of datapoints of about an hour in time from a sensor that retrieves data 20 times per second. Along with it I receive timestamps of a periodic event in this data in the format of `%Y-%m-d %H:%M:%S.%f`, which looks e.g. like this `2019-05-23 17:50:34.346000`.

I now created a method to calculate these periodic events myself and was wondering how I could evalute my methods accuracy. My calculations are sometimes bigger and sometimes smaller by a few milliseconds compared to the actual timestamp. But when I run my own calculated timestamp against the actual timestamp by using pythons `scipy.stats.pearsonr(x,y)` method, I always receive a correlation of nearly 1. I assume that‘s because these small differences in the order of millisenconds don‘t seem relevant in an hour of data. But how could I evaluate the accuracy of two timestamps a reasonable way? Are there better metrics to use than the correlation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to compute a linear statistical correlation (pearson) for something that is, by nature, a timeseries data. This will not tell you much and drawing a conclusion based on the results is dangerous.

It so happens that your two vectors `x` and `y` are growing linearly in the same direction which is not surprising given that they are timestamps.

Let's take an example for stationary data and time series data:

**Time series data:**

Your sensor starts giving measurements at time `t1` and continues to do so until time `t2` is reached. You compute the periodic event's timestamp using your own method then compare it to the actual timestamp. However, there is no reliable way using linear statistical correlations to see if the two are related and how related are they.

**Stationary data :**

Now consider the same sensor giving measurements, but now instead of computing your periodic events all at once, take a single event and compute it multiple times using your empirical data using different measurements (so forget about any notion of time at this point (i.e. repeat the measurement multiple times). The result can be averaged and an *error on the mean* can be computed (see info on standard error). This, now, can be compared to your single event. Based on the error, you can get a more or less *feel* of how good or bad your method is.

I would recommend the following :

- You have your ground truth answer (say, the periodic event) `y_truth`. You compute a vector of the periodic events based on your sensor and your own method mapped as a function  `f(sensor_input) = y_measured`
- Now you have two vectors, one measured and one that is ground truth. In each of those vectors, you have an indicator of a the periodic events such as an  `id`. I would repeat the whole set of measurements, on all  `id`'s tens of times.
- For each 'id' I would compute whatever measurement you are looking for (either a timestamp or time in seconds or whatever...) then I would subtract the two timestamps :  `|y_truth - y_measured|`. This is called residuals or in other words, your error.
- Now averging all the residuals of all the `id`'s gives you something called mean absolute error (`1/n * sum (|y_truth - y_measured|`) which you can very confidently use to report how much error, in a unit of time (seconds for example), your method produces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your explanation sounds very reasonable. Do you have any additional information on the interpretation of the standard error? With correlations I always think it’s quite good to interpret wether the results are accurate or not. Are there any heuristics that would help me determine if my method is accurate or less likely to be recommended to be used?

Comment: Of course! To better understand the standard error, think of the following question : How well does the measured average that I have at hand represent the true average of a population? If you were to take many averages of a measurement, you have a distribution similar to a gaussian bell curve (that is essentially the central limit theorem). If you take the standard deviation of that distribution, well, that is the standard error! The more averages you take, the smaller the error gets until it converges towards the true average

Comment: How to determine if your method is good or bad entirely depends on how much error is tolerated in your study. If you are looking to measure something up to a 10 millisecond accuracy, then a standard error of 5 milliseconds is probably okay (your measurement + or - 5 milliseconds in this case)... However, if your standard error is, say, 20 milliseconds, then it is probably worthless... I hope this gives a better intuition on error analysis!